# Ember Cli not compiling with broccoli-emblem-compiler

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs, emblem.js

I am trying to set up this repository locally https://github.com/lrdiv/ember-soundcloud and i have come across to this issue with broccoli-emblem-compiler. [See the image in attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Gu6.jpg)[image: terminal error]

From my understanding the broccoli-emblem-compiler is not able to compile my emblem templates and i don't know how i can figure it out.

These are all the steps i have done to install and set up the project with Ember-Cli

```
ember new soundcloud

ember install:addon ember-cli-coffeescript

ember install:npm broccoli-emblem-compiler
```

I have deleted the app folder and replace with the project https://github.com/lrdiv/ember-soundcloud that i have cloned

then i have installed the other node modules required

```
ember install:npm broccoli-static-compiler

ember install:npm broccoli-merge-trees  

ember install:npm install body-parser
```

and at the end i run

`ember server` , and in my terminal i get that error i have attached.

What can i do now to sort this out? What's really the problem?

Comment: For posterity: I was looking into this error to. Have it since I tried to deploy today. Cannot read property 'original' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'original' of undefined. To be clear: I have no solution yet. On my mac it builds OK, on Ubuntu server this error happens with 'ember build'.

Comment: I am on Mac and i can not make it running for that error, do you have a repository to check where can i make some code comparisons? Do you add it to Grunt file? i don't. This is my repository https://github.com/Mannaio/SoundCloud

Comment: Same issue here. I have found an old emblem.js issue that might be related https://github.com/machty/emblem.js/issues/116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into problems with `broccoli-emblem-compiler`, but just had success with  `ember-cli-emblem-hbs-printer` -

https://github.com/201-created/ember-cli-emblem-hbs-printer

Answer (score 3):

I did many things to try to fix this. One was replacing the project broccoli-emblem-compiler with this line in the project settings:

"broccoli-emblem-compiler": "git+https://github.com/cascalheira/broccoli-emblem-compiler.git"

At some time the error went away, I think it was when I used this repository. It is mentioned in the other issues.

Comment: Do you mind to attach a print screen image to see exactly where i can replace it?

Comment: In package.json, under devDependencies

Comment: It didn't work out with your answer.  I have seen that project is using "broccoli-emblem-compiler": "^0.3.16" which has handlebars dependencies 1.3. I am using "broccoli-emblem-compiler": "^0.3.19" which needs as dependencies handlebars 2.0 and at the moment my handlebars version is 1.3. I dont know what is better, using broccoli-emblem-compiler 0.3.16 and not updating handlebars 2.0 or upgrade the handlebars 2.0 with my emblem-compiler 0.3.19 ( with the risk that some emblem syntax gets broken) ? I am looking forward to your recommendations and answer @HugoLogmans

Comment: In the past days I upgraded to handlebars 2.0 and latest ember, ember-cli etc. Everything seems to work fine except I had to ditch Easyform, that does not work yet. Emblem was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by specifying a version of emblem.js in my package.json file.

Specifically, I added the following line:

`"emblem": "0.3.14"`

Comment: not lucky yet, i have started from scratch again and i got an other issue

Comment: Server is now running! , but i got an other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754626/ember-cli-error-spawn-enoent