# Ember - Cli Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am cloning this  [project](https://github.com/lrdiv/ember-soundcloud) to run locally.

These are the steps i have done in my Terminal

```
git clone https://github.com/lrdiv/ember-soundcloud.git
cd ember soundcloud
ember install 
ember server
```

I got this errors  in my Terminal:

[image]
[image]

And this is what i see in my http://localhost:4200/

[image]

Server is runnings, so this is good sign! but how can i fix it?

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions in the README of the project you linked?

Comment: yes following also the  http://www.ember-cli.com/#getting-started "Cloning an existing project"

Comment: @Dhaulagiri [`ember install`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/2800) is indeed a valid command, just a shortcut to the npm and bower installs.

Comment: Hadn't seen that, thanks @steveax

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ember-cli-sass` instead of `broccoli-ruby-sass` in your package.json. Especially if you've updated the version of ember-cli from 0.0.39

Edit: It also appears that bootstrap-sass is in a different directory than the one specified in `app/styles/app.sass`